# Proper way to set a property of a controller when using <ui:include>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.3

I have a big form that I need to reuse in multiple pages. So, I decided to create a
`<ui:composition>` that contains the form and include it in some pages (page1.xhtml and page2.xhtml).

**form.xhtml:**

```
<ui:composition ...>
    <!-- The form goes here -->
</ui:composition>
```

This form has a controller called `FormController`.

In page1.xhtml and page2.xhtml I just include the form using a `<ui:include>` tag:

```
<ui:include src="/WEB-INF/.../form.xhtml"/>
```

I need to initialize a property in the FormController bean, so, in page1.xhtml I decided to set an attribute with the Id that I need (for example 5):

```
<c:set var="id" scope="request" value ="5"/>
```

And in the controller I just get the value of this attribute:

```
@PostConstruct
public init() {
    Long id = ((HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()).getAttribute("id");
    //Do some queries to the database
}
```

Until know, everything works fine. But in page2.xhtml the "initialization" of the bean property has to be done after an ajax request, so I used the following code:

```
<h:selectOneMenu ...>
    <f:selectItems ...>
    <f:ajax listener="#{otherBean.doSomething}" render="panel"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:panelGroup id="panel">
    <c:set var="id" scope="request" value ="#{otherBean.id}"/>
    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/.../form.xhtml"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

What is weird is that this works just the first time I select an element in the `<h:selectOneMenu>`. The second time, the `doSomething()` method is called but the panel is not rendered (I don't know why, you know why?), so I decided to explore the following alternative that works well in both pages, but I feel that it isn't a good solution:

```
#{bean.init(otherBean.id)}
<ui:include src="/WEB-INF/modules/company/company.xhtml"/>
```

As you see, I am just calling an `init` method (before the `<ui:include>`) with the argument I need. In the controller I just set the property and do the corresponding queries:

```
public init(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
    //Do some queries
}
```

What do you thing about this solution?

Comment: You can use `<f:ajax listener="#{otherBean.doSomething('MYID')}" render="panel"/>` and `another_init_function('MYID2')` for the 2nd form

Comment: Btw., JSTL `<c:xxx>` tags are all taghandlers and they are executed during view build time, while JSF `<h:xxx>` tags are all UI components and they are executed during view render time.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense/

Comment: But how you call the another_init_function for the first page (in this case there isn't any Ajax request to initialiaze the id in the FormController bean)

Answer (score 0):

If the form has to be initialized at start, you can use

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{otherBean.initSomething('MYID2')}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

If the form has to be initialized by an action

```
<h:commandButton action='#{otherBean.doSomething('MYID1')}'...>
```

or

```
<f:ajax listener="#{otherBean.doSomething('MYID')}" .../>
```

Comment: Thank you Holger. I will try with <f:viewAction> as you suggested. Is there anything wrong calling #{bean.init(otherBean.id)} directly in the xhtml?